# Problema na classe de conexão com banco de dados

Tags: java, android, banco-de-dados

Estou tendo problemas com minha classe de conexão ao banco de dados MySQL no Android Studio.

Erro:

```
    10-16 15:04:02.872      532-532/com.example.dev.mbstore W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljavax/naming/Reference;)
10-16 15:04:02.872      532-532/com.example.dev.mbstore I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method javax.naming.Reference.get, referenced from method com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl$ConnectionProperty.initializeFrom
10-16 15:04:02.872      532-532/com.example.dev.mbstore W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 8068: Ljavax/naming/Reference;.get (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/naming/RefAddr;
10-16 15:04:02.872      532-532/com.example.dev.mbstore D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0004
10-16 15:04:02.882      532-532/com.example.dev.mbstore W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljavax/naming/Reference;)
10-16 15:04:02.882      532-532/com.example.dev.mbstore E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'javax.naming.StringRefAddr', referenced from method com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionPropertiesImpl$ConnectionProperty.storeTo
10-16 15:04:02.882      532-532/com.example.dev.mbstore W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 518 (Ljavax/naming/StringRefAddr;) in Lcom/mysql/jdbc/ConnectionPropertiesImpl$ConnectionProperty;
10-16 15:04:02.882      532-532/com.example.dev.mbstore D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0006
10-16 15:04:02.882      532-532/com.example.dev.mbstore D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x1f86 at 0x14 in Lcom/mysql/jdbc/ConnectionPropertiesImpl$ConnectionProperty;.storeTo
10-16 15:04:03.032      532-540/com.example.dev.mbstore I/dalvikvm﹕ Total arena pages for JIT: 11
10-16 15:04:03.232      532-535/com.example.dev.mbstore D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 167K, 3% free 10724K/11015K, paused 3ms+3ms
10-16 15:04:03.242      532-532/com.example.dev.mbstore I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean, referenced from method com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.appendDeadlockStatusInformation
10-16 15:04:03.242      532-532/com.example.dev.mbstore W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 7453: Ljava/lang/management/ManagementFactory;.getThreadMXBean ()Ljava/lang/management/ThreadMXBean;
10-16 15:04:03.242      532-532/com.example.dev.mbstore D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0079
10-16 15:04:03.351      532-532/com.example.dev.mbstore I/System.out﹕ com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
    +++ LOG: entry corrupt or truncated
10-16 15:04:03.351      532-532/com.example.dev.mbstore I/System.out﹕ The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

Pelo que parece ele não encontra a classe do Driver mas coloquei nas dependências o plugin MySQL e mandei compilar.

Classe conexao:

```
public class DatabaseExport{
    private static Connection conn = null;

    public static void conectaDB(String url, String porta, String banco, String usuario, String senha)
    {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+url+":"+porta+"/"+banco,usuario,senha);
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Exceptions.getException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pelo que eu vejo, está usando classes dos pacotes do Java EE no Android, o que não é permitido. Além disso o problema é na conexão, ele não está conseguindo estabelecer uma conexão. Chegou a considerar usar um Web Service em prol de uma conexão com banco?

Comment: nao teve jeito tive que fazer um webservice com php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema foi resolvido com a criação de um webservice.Aplicativos mobile não suportam conexão direta com banco de dados, foi criado um metodo AsyncTask para fazer a requisição no webservice.
Exemplos:
https://geekjamboree.wordpress.com/2011/11/22/asynctask-call-web-services-in-android/

Answer (score 2):

Não sei como tens o restante das configurações necessárias pelo que vou deixar de forma genérica os passos aos quais deverás estar atento:

1. Fazer download do [MySQL JDBC Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> e incluir o mesmo na `build path` do projeto Android.
2. Fazer a inclusão do que é necessário:

   ```
   import java.sql.Connection;

   import java.sql.DriverManager;
   import java.sql.ResultSet;
   import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
   import java.sql.Statement;
   ```
3. Garantir que o código da ligação `JDBC` está numa [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), de outra forma não consegues interagir com a base de dados.
4. Garantir que está presente a permissão [`INTERNET`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET) que é necessária para abrir `sockets`, ou seja, no teu `manifest` deverás ter:

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   ```
5. Realizar um teste para ver se a ligação correu bem ou existem erros a resolver:

   ```
   try {
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
     Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(endereco, utilizador, password);

     /* Debug: */
     /* System.out.println("Ligação à BD com sucesso."); */
   }
   catch(Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```

Comment: entao eu tentei isso mas parece que o android studio ta dando serios problemas nessa parte, to migrando para o eclipse quando terminar posto uma resposta sobre o fato.